# CSS - Make an item start in the middle of previous row

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

I'm trying to use CSS Grid to have a div that starts in the middle of the div in the row above. I want both divs to wrap around the text. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Aim : the div on the second row starts in the middle of the first div]

As you see on the picture, in some cases, the subtitle might be longer than the title, and sometimes not.

I tried different ways but I can't figure it out. Here's my last attempt. The problem here is that (of course) the "Title" div becomes wider as the subtitle is longer.

```css
#container{
  border:solid black;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
  grid-template-rows:1fr 1fr;
}

#title{
  border:solid blue;
  grid-column:1/2;
  grid-row:1/2;
}

#subtitle-container{
  border:solid red;
  grid-column:1/2;
  grid-row:2/3;
  
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:50% max-content;
}

#subtitle-text{
  border:solid green;
  grid-column:2/3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">Title</div>
  <div id="subtitle-container">
    <div id="subtitle-text">This is a rather long subtitle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to say that CSS-Grid is not really suited for this kind of layout. For one thing *it's **not** a grid*.

Comment: Right, I guess as I just learned CSS-Grid I want to apply it everywhere even when it doesn't suit the issue! What would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Looks like there already a non-grid answer. I'm not really convinced it's the *best* one since it seems *hacky* but that's just an opinion. Perhaps an alternative will come up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea where you can create a hidden float element that will push the subtitle. You simply make the float element 50% width of the title and you need to make the width of the title [`fit-content`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width).

```css
.container{
  border:solid black;
  margin:5px;
}

.title{
  border-bottom:solid blue;
  width:-moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

.title:after {
  content:"";
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  height:2px; /*not needed*/
  background: red; /*not needed*/
  margin-top:10px; /*need to be a small value*/
}
.subtitle-text{
  border:solid green;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="subtitle-text">This is a rather long subtitle</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Long long Title</div>
  <div class="subtitle-text">Subtitle</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Very Long long Title</div>
  <div class="subtitle-text">Subtitle</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had trouble understanding your answer, as it actually doesn't work with my browser (FF62) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uty4r.png

Comment: @MarieD. yes sorry, forget the prefix, you can try again on FF

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is there any alternative so that the solution works with IE?

Comment: @MarieD. I will try to think about a way for IE, but it won't be easy